# Is there a tutorial about NScombobox cocoa with external datasource?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I didn't find a tutorial that shows how to use a combobox with external data. I am a beginner in cocoa. 
Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1):

Apple's **SimpleComboBox** example code demonstrates this.

Answer (score 0):

This [site](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Cocoa/Part+II+API+Quick+Reference/Chapter+16.+Application+Kit+Protocols/NSComboBoxDataSource/) contains some fine explanation about the `NSCombobox` of cocoa